# Can I reverse the arrows in Visio 2013

Tags: microsoft-visio-2013

The arrows are pointing down in my organisation chart. I want to keep the rectangles in same spot but the arrow end should be upwards. Is it possible to reverse the direction of the arrows automatically ?

[image: reverse the arrows in visio 2013]

Comment: Yes of course you can; you click on the lines and the select the type of arrow.  This question is fully on topic I hope people don't close it.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound! Hi Devid what Ramhound is saying what I want to achevie but I dont want to have to click on each connector then go format shape then go "beginning arrow = none" and then set "end arrow = 4". I was hoping i could apply that throughout the chart as clicking each connector would be ton of work

Comment: It's 2 clicks per line....there isn't another way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click on the diagram and select Format Shape. Select the whole diagram by hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. Now in the Format Shape on the right select Begin Arrow Type and choose a type different than 00 (example 04) and for End Arrow Type select none. That will reverse all the arrows in your diagram at once.

[image]